# Firebase pagination with CollectionView always loads the same image

Tags: swift, firebase, pagination

I am trying to implement a pagination in my CollectionView.

Right now, I always get the same picture, when I call my function *loadMorePosts*

I am sure it is because I don't revert the snapshot of my data, so the image will always be on top.

How do I reverse my snapshot to get the correct data?

This is my code to add new data:

```
func loadMorePosts() {

    var numOfItems = posts.count

    let preNumOfItems = numOfItems

    numOfItems += 1

    let REF_POST = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    let REF_QUERY = REF_POST.queryOrdered(byChild: "postDate").queryLimited(toLast: UInt(numOfItems))

    REF_QUERY.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

        var newPost = [PostModel]()
        var count = 0

        for post in snapshot.children {

            let data = post as! DataSnapshot

            print("num of items " + String(numOfItems))
            print("counter " + String(count))

            let lostPost = PostModel(dictionary: data.value as! [String : Any], key: snapshot.key)

            if count >= Int(preNumOfItems) {
                newPost.insert(lostPost, at: 0)
            }
            count+=1
        }
        self.posts += newPost
        self.exploreCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```